# Python - Counter in 2 million row table

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, counter

As an example, I have the following dataframe:

```
Date                     Balance
2013-04-01 03:50:00         A
2013-04-01 04:00:00         A
2013-04-01 04:15:00         B
2013-04-01 04:15:00         B
2013-04-01 04:25:00         A
2013-04-01 04:25:00         A
2013-04-01 04:35:00         B
2013-04-01 04:40:00         B
2013-04-02 04:55:00         B
2013-04-02 04:56:00         A
2013-04-02 04:57:00         A
2013-04-03 10:30:00         A
2013-04-03 16:35:00         A
2013-04-03 20:40:00         A
```

My goal is to add one column 'Counter' that basically shows a balance of the number of A's and B's. So, every time an A appears, the counter column increases one value. Every time B appears, the counter column decreases one value. If two A's appear at the same time (same Date) in two consecutive rows, the balance should increase by two on both of the rows (the same reasoning applies for consecutive B's or for A's and B's at the same time). Therefore, the dataframe would look like this in the end:

```
 Date                     Balance        Counter
2013-04-01 03:50:00         A               1
2013-04-01 04:00:00         A               2
2013-04-01 04:15:00         B               0
2013-04-01 04:15:00         B               0
2013-04-01 04:25:00         A               2
2013-04-01 04:25:00         A               2
2013-04-01 04:35:00         B               1
2013-04-01 04:40:00         B               0
2013-04-02 04:55:00         B              -1
2013-04-02 04:56:00         A               0
2013-04-02 04:57:00         A               1
2013-04-03 10:30:00         A               2
2013-04-03 16:35:00         A               3
2013-04-03 20:40:00         A               4
```

The major problem is that the dataframe has more than 2 millions rows, therefore it is really time consuming to perform a loop. Is there any way to implement a vectorized approach to this problem?

Edit (I was able to compile a solution that works well if the dates are not the same on consecutive rows). Anyone could help me to figure out the rest?

```
d = {'Date': ['2013-04-01 03:50:00', '2013-04-01 04:00:00','2013-04-01 
04:15:00','2013-04-01 04:15:00','2013-04-01 04:25:00',
'2013-04-01 04:25:00','2013-04-01 04:35:00','2013-04-01 04:40:00','2013-04- 
02 04:55:00','2013-04-02 04:56:00',         
'2013-04-02 04:57:00','2013-04-03 10:30:00','2013-04-03 16:35:00','2013-04- 
03 20:40:00'], 'Balance': ['A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B','B',                                                                                                
'A','A','A','A','A',]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['plus_minus'] = np.where(df.Balance == 'A', 1, -1)
df['Counter'] = df['plus_minus'].cumsum()
```

Comment: I'm not sure your example output and description match up? Why isn't it either `[2, 2, 0, 0...]` or `[1, 2, 1, 0...]` ?

Comment: @JonClements I think it's because when there are two consecutive A's or B's, it's adding 2 units right away, instead of going up 1 unit twice.

Comment: Miguel, could you show us what you've worked on so far?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. The first two dates are different. Therefore should be [1,2]. Then, the third and fourth dates are exactly the same, therefore, the counter should decrease by two on both of them. So, the first four numbers should be [1,2,0,0]

Comment: @MiguelLambelho but you didn't mention that `Date` was involved in the logic... only "consecutive rows" and the `Balance` column...

Comment: why not add another column that defines the increments and the decrements according to the first 2 columns, and compute the cumsum of that column?

Comment: Sorry @JohnClements. Yes, it is always based on the date.

Comment: @StephenWitkowski, I just edited the question.

Comment: @AmitWolfenfeld, my draft solution is precisely that. However, I do not know how to deal with same dates in consecutive rows with this approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach would be to group by the Date and sum the values.  The cumulative sum of that gives you the net at end of that datetime, and then we can reindex by the Date to broadcast the result back up to the main frame:

```
df['plus_minus'] = np.where(df.Balance == 'A', 1, -1)
by_dt = df["plus_minus"].groupby(df["Date"]).sum().cumsum()
df["Counter2"] = by_dt.reindex(df.Date).values
```

gives me

```
                   Date Balance  Counter  plus_minus  Counter2
0   2013-04-01 03:50:00       A        1           1         1
1   2013-04-01 04:00:00       A        2           1         2
2   2013-04-01 04:15:00       B        0          -1         0
3   2013-04-01 04:15:00       B        0          -1         0
4   2013-04-01 04:25:00       A        2           1         2
5   2013-04-01 04:25:00       A        2           1         2
6   2013-04-01 04:35:00       B        1          -1         1
7   2013-04-01 04:40:00       B        0          -1         0
8   2013-04-02 04:55:00       B       -1          -1        -1
9   2013-04-02 04:56:00       A        0           1         0
10  2013-04-02 04:57:00       A        1           1         1
11  2013-04-03 10:30:00       A        2           1         2
12  2013-04-03 16:35:00       A        3           1         3
13  2013-04-03 20:40:00       A        4           1         4
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the way to go. I hadn't appreciated that last condition, which wasn't present in the sample.